# How to express hypothetical judgements for hypothetical situations?

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

> I don't think this viral video deserves its fame, on the other hand, **I
>   probably wouldn't be saying that** if there wasn't some intricate
>   marketing behind it.

Is this a way to express acknowledgement of the limits of my own judgement based on selective information? Is the tense correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tense is correct, and the meaning seems clear enough.  You could have used the "were subjunctive"  (... if there weren't some ...") but it isn't needed.